# Numeric column to INET postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to run the following update in PSQL:

```
update ip2proxy_ipv6 set block = inet_merge(inet '::0' + ip_from::bigint, inet '::0' + ip_to::bigint) where true
```

But I am getting error:

```
[22003] ERROR: bigint out of range
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: What are the values for ip_from and ip_to and what type are they to begin with?

Comment: I ended up ditching this technique :( - the numbers were really large - larger than BIGINT - so using any number larger than BIGINT will give same effect

Comment: Where they actually numbers or text?  What I'm trying to say is if ip_* are actually IP addresses there should be a way to make this work.

Comment: They are large numbers - NUMERIC  type (not text)

Comment: You might to rework your question to show what is you want the result to be. The general form you are using is not going to work anyway: ```select inet_merge(('::0' + 10000::text)::inet, ('::0' + 10000::text)::inet);
ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown + text
LINE 1: select inet_merge(('::0' + 10000::text)::inet, ('::0' + 1000...
``` or : ```select inet_merge(('::0'|| 10000::text)::inet, ('::0' || 10000::text)::inet);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type inet: "::010000"```